# MVC4 routing @Html.ActionLink and @Html.RouteLink producing wrong urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url, routes, url-routing

Maybe someone may help me to understand why `@Html.ActionLink` and  `@Html.RouteLink`  producing the wrong links in some cases.

I have routes declared like that:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Catalog", // Route name
                "Catalog/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Index", a = UrlParameter.Optional, b = UrlParameter.Optional, c = UrlParameter.Optional, d = UrlParameter.Optional, e = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I have controller with my params:

```
public ActionResult Index(string a, string b, string c, string d, string e)
        {
        //Do stuff;
        }
```

I have list of cases with `@Html.RouteLink` and `@Html.ActionLink` on the view declared like that:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("ActionLink1","Index", new { a = "a" }, null)
    @Html.ActionLink("ActionLink2","Index", new { a = "a", b = "b" }, null)
    @Html.ActionLink("ActionLink3","Index", new { a = "a", b = "b", c = "c" }, null)
    @Html.ActionLink("ActionLink4","Index", new { a = "a", b = "b", c = "c", d = "d" }, null)
    @Html.ActionLink("ActionLink5","Index", new { a = "a", b = "b", c = "c", d = "d", e = "e" }, null)
    <br/>
    @Html.RouteLink("RouteLink1","Catalog", new { a = "a" })
    @Html.RouteLink("RouteLink2","Catalog", new { a = "a", b = "b" })
    @Html.RouteLink("RouteLink3","Catalog", new { a = "a", b = "b", c = "c" })
    @Html.RouteLink("RouteLink4","Catalog", new { a = "a", b = "b", c = "c", d = "d" })
    @Html.RouteLink("RouteLink5","Catalog", new { a = "a", b = "b", c = "c", d = "d", e = "e" 
})
```

### The Results

**Current url** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog`

`ActionLink1`

- **Actual Result:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog?a=a`
- **Expected Result:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a`

`RouteLink1`

- **Actual Result:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog`
- **Expected Results:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a`

---

**Current url** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a`

`ActionLink1`

- **Actual Result:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog?a=a`
- **Expected Results:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a`

---

**Current url** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b`

`ActionLink1`

- **Actual Result:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b`
- **Expected Results:**`http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a`

`RouteLink1`

- **Actual Result:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b`
- **Expected Results:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a`

---

**Current url** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b/c`

`ActionLink1`

- **Actual Result:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b/c`
- **Expected Results:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a`

`RouteLink1`

- **Actual Result:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b/c`
- **Expected Results:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a`

`ActionLink2`

- **Actual Results:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b/c`
- **Expected Results:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b`

`RouteLink2`

- **Actual Results:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b/c`
- **Expected Results:** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b`

And so on...

---

**Current url** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b/c/d`

ActionLink1, ActionLink2 and ActionLink3 as well as RouteLink1, RouteLink2, and RouteLink3 are all producing wrong urls.

---

**Current url** `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b/c/d/e`

**All** ActionLinks and RouteLinks (exept ActionLink5 and RouteLinks5) are producing wrong urls.

---

I put a sample project here: http://www.mediafire.com/?gdbatoafgd0kf4w

May be someone can figure out why that is happening?

That story started some days ago when i was trying to build Breadcrumbs with `MvcSiteMapProvider`, and i got same links produced by `MvcSiteMapProvider Breadcrumbs`.
During my research i figure out that `MvcSiteMapProvider` not causing the problem the problem somewhere else. So i created default MVC4 project and it has such strange behavior by default.

**UPDATE**

It is looks like when you are using `@Html.ActionLink` and `@Html.RouteLink` helpers url generated based on current url..but still can't understand why when `Current url` `http://localhost:2288/Catalog` I am getting:

`http://localhost:2288/Catalog?a=a` instead of `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a` in case of `ActionLink`

and `http://localhost:2288/Catalog` instead of `http://localhost:2288/Catalog/a` in case of `RouteLink`

Comment: think this post will answer you question http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx

Comment: also existing route values are used when generating url. Causing ActionLink1 = 'localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b/c'; in CurrentUrl = 'localhost:2288/Catalog/a/b/c';. Unfortunately you have to explicitly set these values to string.Empty in the actionlink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The RouteLink allows you to explicitly specify a route name. The ActionLink evaluates the routes in the order they appeared in your route definitions. Your first route declaration is invalid and is the reason why the ActionLink helper is unable to capture it. The reason why your first route definition is invalid is because you made the `{a}`, `{b}`, `{c}` and `{d}` route parameters as `UrlParameter.Optional` but only the **LAST** parameter (`{e}` in your example) of an uri path can be optional.

Since `RouteLink` helper allows you to explicitly state which route you want to be picked up, you could use it as a workaround.

Comment: The idea is that in my case any of parameters could be optional. If no params(`localhost:2288/Catalog`) you see the list of items and then by clicking each you "digging" in to details untill you reach the last `e` param. And also for me looking strange why i am getting  
`localhost:2288/Catalog?a=a` instead of `localhost:2288/Catalog/a`...

Comment: I understand your idea and explained you the limitation of the routing engine in that aspect. There's nothing strange in why you are getting `localhost:2288/Catalog?a=a`. The reason for that is because the second route is matched: `{controller}/{action}`. The reason for that is because your first is invalid. Only the last argument of a route can be optional.

Comment: How can i fix that? Not sure that i understanding the the aspects 100% right. I installed RouteDebugger and it is showing that all that urls matched to that route `Catalog/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}`

Comment: You could use the RouteLink helper.

Comment: So as far as i understand there is no issues with routes definition? The problem with helpers?

Comment: You might need to put constraints on your route definitions or the routing engine might not be able to disambiguate between the routes. As far as generating the urls are concerned, you will need to use the RouteLink helpers if you want to have such pattern.

Comment: Ok i clearly see the problem now. But as i said the reason why i started to dig in to it because of `MvcSiteMapProvider Breadcrumbs` was producing a wrong urls. I can fix the routes RouteConfig.cs but it is will not fix the `MvcSiteMapProvider Breadcrumbs` urls